# Code with No Errors, Undesired Result

Tags: c++

When I run the code, the user is not prompted for input like I desire. A text box opens that can be typed in, but after typing in.. say your name.. and pressing Enter, nothing happens. The issue specifically I am having is that the user receives no prompts that will later be inserted into the 'story' at the bottom of my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
//list of variables to be stored 
    string Name; 
    string City;
    int Age;
    string College;
    string Job;
    string Animal;
    string petName;

//user prompts to be answered by user input
    cin >> Name; 
    cin >> City;
    cin >> Age;
    cin >> College;
    cin >> Job;
    cin >> Animal;
    cin >> petName;

//The output story which will include the user input as part of the final result
    cout << "There once was a person named " + Name + " who lived in " + City + "." "At the age of " << endl;
    cout << Age + ", " + Name + " went to college at " + College + "." + Name + " graduated and went to work" << endl;
    cout << " as a " + Job + ". Then," + Name + " adopted a(n)" + Animal + " named " + petName + ". They" << endl;
    cout << "both lived happily ever after!";

}
```

Comment: C++ doesn't provide a default prompt or anything. This is consistent with every other language I know of.

Comment: As a secondary, after posting my code here I see that the variable 'petName' is not blue text like my other variables?

Comment: Thanks for your comment chris. My goal is for the user to be prompted for their input: name, age, college, animal and etc. Can you point me in the right direction to have the user prompted so that their input is inserted into the story?

Comment: It's not capitalised. The common convention in C++ is to use capitalised names for classes.

Comment: @NicholasNunez, of course, your naming convention is horrendous. I'm also not sure why you like the `+` operator so much. As to your actual question, I'm not sure what the issue is. You obviously know about `cout`, just use it.

Comment: @NicholasNunez: You obviously know how to output text to the console. Think about that can be used to "prompt" the user for input...

Comment: @NicholasNunez, Remember that (until much later) every line of code in a function will execute in the order it appears. A prompt is just an output and you know when you want the output to appear.

Comment: @Blindy , originally my code had every '+' replaced with '<<' but it was giving me errors. After searching here on Stack, the answer was to replace with them with '+'. I will say though, I MIGHT have had that error before I figured out one of my other problems, I forgot to add the #include <string> originally in my code but have since fixed that.

Comment: @Blindy I used the cout like you said and solved my problem. It seems so simple in retrospect.

Comment: @chris thank you again for your second response, your wording helped clear things up for me A Lot.

Comment: @Blastfurnace thank you, your comment lead me in the right direction as well. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

```
//user prompts to be answered by user input
cout << "Enter your name:";
cin >> Name; 

cout << "Enter your City:";
cin >> City;

cout << "Enter your Age:";
cin >> Age;
```

Comment: I figured it out after reading some other Stack user's comments to my original code, Thanks!

Comment: 31.9k users should not speak like that.